# iOS: How to reload cell at indexPath without animation?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have UITableView with cells. When i select cell - height increased, when i select this cell again - height decreased. In method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" i use this -

```
NSArray *indArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSIndexPath*)[timer userInfo], nil];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

But "UITableViewRowAnimationFade" animation has faded effect, and cell is flickered.
I tried another animations, but they also unsuitable(

How i can avoid this effect and update cell without animation?

Comment: @Nubasian, any more questions? :)

Answer (score 21):

Setting the row animation to .None doesn't work - there is still stuff going on and moving about. In my case, some cells changed height, which caused the table view to scroll.

To hold perfectly still, do this:

```
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation({ 
        let loc = tableView.contentOffset
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        tableView.contentOffset = loc
    })
```

Comment: Big help. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: This did not work for me - Swift 5 with slightly different syntax, iOS 13. For some reason contentOffset is 0.0 even though I've scrolled well down into the table.

Comment: @AndyWeinstein Thanks, updating for Swift 5 - if contentOffset is 0 then you're measuing something else, maybe your entire tableview is inside another scrollview or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

self.yourTableView.beginUpdates()

self.yourTableView.reloadRows(at: yourIndexPath, with:UITableViewRowAnimation.none)

self.yourTableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look in the [documentation of UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewRowAnimation), there is a value for the rowAnimation called `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`, which won't animate anything. Try this instead:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```